# How to add OS-specific complier flags in .clangd file?

Tags: clang, clangd

I configured `clangd` using `nvim-lspconfig`. Now I would like to enable `AVX` support for certain projects in Linux.

How can I detect OS type in `.clangd` file, and then add `-mavx` flag only when it is Linux?

```yaml
CompileFlags:
  Add: [-xavx]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be good to do that by leveraging an external script or a build system which is able to detect OS and construct `if`. As for `Makefile`:

```
arch := $(shell uname -m)

ifeq ($(arch), arm64)
define CLANG_FLAGS
CompileFlags:
    Add: [-Wall]
endef
else
define CLANG_FLAGS
CompileFlags:
    Add: [-Wall, -mavx]
endef
endif

config:
    @$(file > .clangd,$(CLANG_FLAGS))
```

To generate an OS-specific `.clangd`, just run `make config`.